# In jqplot what does tick mean?

Tags: javascript, charts, jqplot

I'm learning jqplot, I have readed the documentation but I don't understand what is a tick, anyone can help me in jqplot what does tick mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the documentation.](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-axisTickRenderer-js.html)

> A “tick” object showing the value of a tick/gridline on the plot.

They are the labels with values on each axis.

[image: Example graph with ticks/labels]